# How come lvextend allocates less than the specified amount of space?

Tags: bash, shell, lvm, disk-usage, df

I am trying to extend a volume, let's call it `/dev/vol1`.  I see the initial volume size is 500MB when I call:

`df --block-size=M /dev/vol1`

then to extend it 100MB more I call:

```
lvextend -L+100M /dev/vol1
resize2fs /dev/vol1
```

but when I check the size again with

`df --block-size=M /dev/vol1`

I get back 595, indicating only 95 MB were gained.  What accounts for this discrepancy?  I think it has to do with a MB being 1024 vs 1000 KB, but I'm not sure how where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify a size for LVM utilities, capital letters denote decimal units (K=1000, M=1000000, etc.) while lowercase letters denote binary units (k=1024, m=1048576, etc.). This is mentioned in the `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs` man pages but not in the man pages for other commands that take a size argument. You extended the volume by 100,000,000 bytes ≈ 95MiB.

Comment: Also, there is a ~1.5% difference in `df` space and `lvs` space due to the `ext3` filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `lvscan` or `lvdisplay` or `lvs` to see the actual details of a logical volume.

`df -h` reports with M  =  1,048,576 bytes.

`df -H` reports with M  =  1,000,000 bytes.